# Connecting Prolog File with PHP file

Tags: php, prolog

I have a Prolog code `data.pl`, and I need to use it from a PHP file. From my search in internet, I found this:

```
exec('start <path/to/prolog> -f data.pl -g elem(a,[a,b])', $output)
```

I've tried this with `Shell-exec()` and `system()` commands, but they do not work either. I've also tried to correct the directory paths, and move `data.pl` to `path/to/prolog` folder, and still no result. Can anybody help me on this issue?

Comment: If you're using SWI-Prolog (and perhaps, even if you aren't), then http://www.j-paine.org/dobbs/prolog_from_php.html might be of some help.

Comment: @sharky;   This is the page where i took the code, and i tried every code from here. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to integrating a web application with a Prolog application can be using SWI's built-in HTTP server.  It will spare you the need to load Prolog and parse the input file with every call.  It also provides a more web-ish integration, as you can use AJAX and similar approaches.

If you insist on invoking the Prolog executable itself from the PHP runtime env., you'll have to provide some more details.  What errors do you get in your PHP logs?  Have you checked file permissions?  Did you try giving full paths to both the Prolog executable and data file?  Just saying "it doesn't work" is a statement, not a question.

Finally, for efficiency issues, it is advisable to compile the Prolog data file into a quick load format (QLF) instead of re-parsing it with each request.

Comment: Let me explain what i need to make: I need to make a php page where i can use one prolog file which will help me to test some predicates and to do some works (to give me solutions). With the code that i have tested till know i don't receive any solution, mean, when i execute the php file the IE doesn't open me the page (the circle all time is rotating). I don't receive any error message, that's why i can't define the problem. I'm open in every kind of solution to try, just to realize this...

Comment: @akasya, I can't know what's wrong with your PHP environment without seeing some log or trace.  Try adding print messages to hunt the problem down.  Also, try running the command line you embedded in PHP from the command prompt, to see if it works at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'start' command will force the program to run in a new session, and the IO pipes are not inerited. My DOS experience is a bit rusty - but there's a lot of things which would be interpreted as shell metachars on a Unix machine in that statement. Assuming the Prolog interpreter uses STDIO, the command should be:

```
  $cmd='C:\\Program Files\\pl\\bin\\plwin -f data.pl -g elem(a,[a,b])';
  // $cmd=escapeshellcmd($cmd); // in case you're still having problems
  exec($cmd, $output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your care, I tried this method but doesn't work. When i execute the .php file where i wrote this code, internet explorer doesn't open the page (the circle of IE all time is rotating). There is any error message or something else. That's why i don't know where is the problem. What can i try something else?